# How do I call an object in a prepressor only once

Tags: theming, hooks

In drupal8 is there a way to call a function only once in the theme layer. Can I call this function only once and not on other preprocessor hooks or 
am I using the wrong hook?

```
function template_preprocess(&$vars){
    //-- can I call this function only once and not on other preprocessor hooks
    _updateFieldOnNode('field_metatag_title');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call the preprocess hook on nodes only you can use [template_preprocess_node()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/8.2.x).